# Foundation Zurb Equalizer Issue

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation, equalizer

I'm having trouble with Foundation Zurb's data equalizer plugin on a project I'm working on. The following code is what's in play:

```
<div class="row lmt" data-equalizer="listings">


    <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns ">
        <div class="car-listing" data-equalizer-watch="listings">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 medium-5 large-5 columns">
                    <a href="/raes-edit/used-cars/audi-a6-2.0tdi-se-177ps-model/">
                        <img src="/raes-edit/site/assets/files/1234/p1060436.185x0.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="small-12 medium-7 large-7 columns">
                    <a href="/raes-edit/used-cars/audi-a6-2.0tdi-se-177ps-model/">
                        <h4 class="red">Audi A6 2.0TDI SE 177Ps model<br/>Metallic Grey<br />5 Door</h4>
                    </a>

                    <div class="pricing">
                        <p><strong>&pound;18700</strong><br />Saloon / Diesel</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="view" href="/raes-edit/used-cars/audi-a6-2.0tdi-se-177ps-model/"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns  end">
        <div class="car-listing" data-equalizer-watch="listings">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 medium-5 large-5 columns">
                    <a href="/raes-edit/used-cars/landrover-discovery-2.7-tdv6-xs-7seat/">
                        <img src="/raes-edit/site/assets/files/1221/p1060286.185x0.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="small-12 medium-7 large-7 columns">
                    <a href="/raes-edit/used-cars/landrover-discovery-2.7-tdv6-xs-7seat/">
                        <h4 class="red">Landrover Discovery 2.7 TDV6 XS 7SEAT<br/>Metalic Black<br />5 Door</h4>
                    </a>

                    <div class="pricing">
                        <p><strong>&pound;16800</strong><br />Four Wheel Drive / Diesel</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="view" href="/raes-edit/used-cars/landrover-discovery-2.7-tdv6-xs-7seat/"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

It's basically not equalizing. If I remove the "row" class on line 1, it works but breaks the container boundaries. Any ideas how to make this work within the row div?

Thanks!
Graham

Comment: Code works fine here. Any chance there are custom styling being applied to `.row` ?

Comment: Nothing I can see with Firebug's inspector - I tend to avoid overrides so I'm completely baffled. Thanks for confirming it works at your end, at least - what browser are you using? I'm testing on Firefox v38 here

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! It turns out I had to apply a fixed height to the title variable  - its mixed lengths were throwing it off, so forcing a height of 90px aligned it all perfectly!

```
<a href="/raes-edit/used-cars/landrover-discovery-2.7-tdv6-xs-7seat/" style="height: 90px;">
<h4 class="red">Landrover Discovery 2.7 TDV6 XS 7SEAT<br/>Metalic Black<br />5 Door</h4>
</a>
```